# Converting Datetimeoffet datatype of sql server to use in python data frame

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a column in tale having data type as datetime offset. While querying data and storing in dataframe of pandas in python I am getting error

`Arguments: (ProgrammingError('ODBC SQL type -155 is not yet supported.  column-index=1  type=-155', 'HY106'),)`

How do I convert that to a value to be used in a dataframe. The value must be accurate conversion.

And I am exporting data frame to excel so date properties must also hold in excel like filtering and sorting.

Comment: So, for a specific value, what are you after? You can convert a `datetimeoffset` to any of the other date and time data types, but it just won't have the offset; so what value would you want? If the value is `2020-05-16T16:31:00+01:00` what would you expect? What about `2019-10-17T19:12:07-05:00`?

Comment: any conversion is fine, just value should be correct after conversion and in same date format. Can ignore the offset (after using it while converting)

Comment: So what's wrong with the `CONVERT`/`CAST` functions..?

Comment: I couln't find a similar format using convert

Comment: What do you mean a "similar format"? Date and Time data type don't have a format, they are binary values.